# Title: Popup window not appearing in the correct position - what's wrong with my code?

Tags: android, popupwindow

I am working on an Android app that uses a popup window to display additional information when a user interacts with a specific view. However, I'm having trouble getting the popup window to appear in the correct position. Currently, the popup window appears at the top-left corner of the screen, rather than at the location of the user's touch event.

Here is the relevant code that I am using to create and show the popup window:

```java
holder.binding.getRoot().setOnTouchListener((view, motionEvent) -> {
   ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
   if (viewGroup != null){
       viewGroup.removeView(view);
   }
    int x = (int) motionEvent.getX();
    int y = (int) motionEvent.getY();
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        View view1 = View.inflate(ChatActivity.this, R.layout.chat_popup, null);
        int width = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int height = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(view1, width, height, true);
        popupWindow.getContentView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (popupWindow.getContentView().getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            popupWindow.getContentView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {                  
            popupWindow.showAtLocation( binding.getRoot(), Gravity.NO_GRAVITY,x,y );
            popupWindow.getContentView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    return true;
})
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is causing the popup window to appear in the top instead of where i tapped, and how I can fix it? Thank you in advance for any suggestions or advice!